# Why implication can only be in one way for a sentence in Propositional Logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Consider the English sentence:

> If a person is cool or funny, then he is popular.

We have `c` for cool, `f` for funny and `p` for popular.

I don't see why the above sentence can only be written as `c v f => p` in propositional logic. If a person is cool or if a person is funny then it must be the case that the person is popular, I understand that.
But can't I also write it as `p => c v f`?

Just as I writing this I realized there could be other ways he can become popular. Is this the reason why we can't write `p => c v f` for this sentence?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Be careful: you defined $p$ twice, and differently.

Comment: Yes, you got it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Just as I writing this I realized there could be other ways he can become popular. Is this the reason why we can't write $p \to c \lor f$ for this sentence?

That's exactly it. The statement $p\to c\lor f$ means "If the person is popular, then he is either cool or funny". This excludes, for example, the possibility that the person is popular for being attractive.

Answer (score 1):

When we write

$$P \implies Q $$

We mean that, whenever $P $ happens, $Q $ must happen. For example, whenever I watch a horror movie ($P $), I get scared like hell ($Q $).

So we have

$$P \implies Q $$

But can I also automatically write
$Q \implies P $?

It depends! Is it the case that, whenever I get scared, I am watching a horror movie? Hell no! Sometimes friends hide behind doors and whatnot to scare me, and in those cases $Q $ happens, but $P $ doesn't happen. It is the same in your case.

If you could write $Q\implies P $ whenever you have $P\implies Q $ then you would always have $P \iff Q $, meaning that $P $ and $Q $ always happen together. Which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

$c \lor f \implies p$ says that if a person is cool or funny, then he is popular.

$p \implies c \lor f$ says that if a person is popular, then he is cool or funny.

This is not the same as the original statement (as the original statement does not restrict popularity to only being funny or cool).

However, if we have: a person is popular if and only if he is cool or funny, then we can write $c \lor f \iff p$.